# Orchard How can I style the summary of list items different in a page versus a widget

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, orchardcms

I am new to the orchard project, and have not been able to track down how this could be done (assuming its possible).

I have a data list called "Events" in which I have attached a list of custom data type objects which are of type "Event".  I then have put a view of this list in a widget on my homepage - as well as displayed the list view page by adding it to my main menu.

I have found the information to update the summary of these list items by adding the proper view
for example adding the following view:

\Themes\PeaceCamp\Views\Items\Content-Event.Summary.cshtml

```
<div class="event">
<b>@Model.Title</b><br />
</div>
```

however this seems to update the view in the widget, as well as in the list view page.  Since pagination only affects the page view - I presume there is a way to summarize them different in the two different areas - hoping someone could explain or direct me to the proper location to do that - Thanks!

My solution is all local at this time, so I cannot provide links as examples - and the only thing not done in the CMS would be the view added above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add your own IShapeTableProvider (the stuff you describe comes from the Shapes class in Orchard.Core.Contents) that walks up the shape tree to find a parent zone and adds alternates accordingly.
This post might give you some ideas on how to do that:
http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2011/01/10/orchard-shapeshifting.aspx

Comment: this sounds like the right direction, i haven't actually gotten it to work as of yet - but seems like the right path.  Will update if i actually track down a working solution with this guidance - thanks!